# Преобразовать столбцы в строки в JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Немного изучал только JS, поэтому пишу в нем.
Задача: есть данные социологического опроса, они вбиты столбцом.
Вид примерно следующий:

```
*222  
1 3 5  
2 3 4  
1 2  
*223  
2  
3 4  
1
```

Звездочкой обозначен номер анкеты. Строки - вопросы в анкете. Цифры в строках - выбранные варианты ответов на вопрос.
Необходимо данные преобразовать в csv формат, для дальнейшего импорта в Excel. В нем будут по порядку столбцами все вопросы отображены и все варианты ответов на них. Выбранные варианты ответов надо отметить как 1, не выбранные как 0. Количество ответов на каждый вопрос известно.
Итого каждая новая строка будет соответствовать новой анкете и если вариантов ответа на 1 вопрос например 6, на 2й - 4, на 3й - 2, то будет выложенный в начале пример должен выглядеть вот так.

```
222;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;  
223;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;
```

Мне кроме того, чтобы создать массив для каждой строки с заданным количеством элементов в голову ничего не пришло, в сторону каких функций смотреть тоже не понятно, поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: Ничерта не понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: я долго разбирался, но принцип понял. Задачка простая, но подход для решения неочевидный, а возможно и неверный.

Comment: Всё путает это - _"Количество ответов на каждый вопрос известно"_. Кому известно? А это одно из главных условий. То же и про количество вариантов - эти вводные зависят друг от друга напрямую.

Comment: Про "количество ответов известно". Эти данные просто изначально есть. Сколько вопросов в анкете, сколько вариантов ответа на каждый вопрос. Их можно хоть вручную заполнить как количество элементов массива для каждой строчки, хоть через интерфейс какой нибудь примитивный, важен конечный результат, а не удобство. Сначала пытался я городить интерфейс, потом понял, что проще укажу прямо в скрипте. Что то вроде. const length = 3; 
  const filledArray = Array(length).fill(0); Это создаст в данном случае массив из трех элементов нулей, останется перезаписать единицами выбранные варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе приведённых данных и условий, если я правильно понял, то здесь уместны регулярные выражения и метод `split()`. Возможно, что кто-нибудь даст ответ более лаконичный, но тут больше наглядность и половина кода - комментарии.

```js
// Массив значений количества вариантов для каждого вопроса
const VARIANTS_NUMB = [6, 4, 2];
// Разбивка на анкеты
const QUESTIONNAIRES = [...source.value.matchAll(/(?:\*)(?<numb>[\d]+)(?<asks>[^*]+)/g)];
/* Перебор анкет */
QUESTIONNAIRES.forEach((q_curr) => {
  // Номер текущей анкеты
  let q_numb = q_curr.groups['numb'];
  // Массив ответов текущей анкеты
  let q_asks = q_curr.groups['asks'].trim().split('\n');
  // Строка для CSV
  let answers = '';
  /* Перебор значений количества вариантов */
  VARIANTS_NUMB.forEach((v_numb, i) => {
    // Массив вариантов
    let variant = q_asks[i].split(' ');
    /* Перебор вариантов */
    for (let v = 1; v <= v_numb; v++) {
      // Добавление значения в результат на основе наличия номера варианта
      answers += `${variant.includes(`${v}`) ? 1 : 0};`;
    }
  });
  // Вывод результата
  target.value += `${q_numb};${answers}\n`;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="source" cols="30" rows="10">
*222
1 3 5
2 3 4
1 2
*223
2
3 4
1
</textarea>
<textarea id="target" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```